# stored procedure to delete entire table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I want to delete all the rows of a table on a button click.the stored procedure is as follows:

```
create proc spTest
as 
begin
     Delete from tblTest
end
```

The code-behind is as follows:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         con.Open();
         lblStatus.Text = "Tasks Deleted Successfully.";
     }
}
```

but the table remains unaffected although the label shows all tasks deleted successfully. What is the problem? I know something is very silly that I am doing.

PS: I don't want to use `Truncate`.

Comment: Missing the execution of the command, however, sometimes it is better to use TRUNCATE TABLE See: [Truncate vs Delete](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1080/deleting-data-in-sql-server-with-truncate-vs-delete-commands/)

Comment: @Steve I don't want the primary Id to start fresh and so i am not using truncate as deleting the entire rows will be a regular action

Comment: @ManishDalal - Thanks.Silly Mistake as i said.

Answer (score 2):

You have created `Command` but did **not** execute it. You have to call [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to exeucte the `Command`

As a addition note, put the code in [try-catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) so that your application does not terminated in case of exception

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         lblStatus.Text = "Tasks Deleted Successfully.";
     }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      lblStatus.Text = "Tasks could not be deleted, Error " + ex.Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks steve, it has to be "note, put" now corrected

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the query using `ExecuteNonQuery` command.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         lblStatus.Text = "Tasks Deleted Successfully.";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never acutally executing your query.

Call it like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     con.Open();
     /*new:*/
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     lblStatus.Text = "Tasks Deleted Successfully.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgoted to execute the command.

add this `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to `Button3_Click` event

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", con);
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         con.Open();
if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
{
         lblStatus.Text = "Tasks Deleted Successfully.";
}
else 
{
         lblStatus.Text = "Unable to  Delete tasks";
}

     }
}
```